# Gap between label and <select> - why?

Tags: css

There is a small gap between `<label>Title</label>` and `<select>` field, I could not figure out what is causing this?

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/xrvbv/6/ and you will notice `<select>` is not align properly.

CSS:

```
.FormStyle label {
 display: inline-block; 
 width: 130px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 7px;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #666;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.FormStyle input[type="text"], .FormStyle textarea {
 padding: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 290px;
 border: 1px solid #BDC7D8;
 border-image: initial;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size: 12px;
}


.FormStyle li {
 padding: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
}


.FormStyle {
 margin: 5px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px 0px 10px;
 list-style-type: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}​
```

HTML

```
<ul class="FormStyle">
    <li>
        <label>First Name</label><input type="text" value="" name="firstname">    
    </li>

    <li>
        <label>Second Name</label><input type="text" value="" name="secondname">    
    </li>
    <li>
       <label>Title</label>
        <select name="title">
            <option> Mr </option>
            <option> Mrs </option>
            <option> Ms </option>
            <option> Miss </option>
            <option> Dr </option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: The gap is a styling issue - hence CSS problem. HTML is for content. Thinking HTML can fix how the page is viewed - you have lost the plot with having CSS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's caused by the whitespace. Change to

```
<label>Title</label><select name="title">
```

and you will see the gap disappear.

If you *really* want to keep your lines separate, you could use comments, as suggested below, or move the closing label's >:

```
   <label>Title</label
        ><select name="title">
```

I don't think either solution is good, and you're just wasting bandwidth sending whitespace you don't want or need.

Comment: But I want on separate line??

Comment: Sadly, the browser does not really care what web developers *actually* want :-)

Comment: Add comments like this <!-- at the end of the first line, and --> at the begining of the second. It cancels the white space. There's also a matter of default styling in chrome.

Comment: Comments are your only option then, so that the whitespace is a comment, not part of the html content. Sorry :-)

Comment: I don't think so, the issue isn't the tag, but the whitespace. HTML treats it as a space separating the label and the select, and correctly renders it. You could move the closing `>` to the select line...

Comment: @craigmj - HTML or even XHTML => content, who much white space does not matter. Just a break between words. CSS => Lets make it pretty! So you answer is incorrect.

Comment: Hi Ed, HTML (or XHTML) treats whitespace as a space. No matter how much whitespace, it will treat it as a single space.

Answer (score 2):

That's because there is a newline and a tab between the `label` and the `select`. If you put the tags on the same line and remove the tab, the gap will disappear.

↪ [View this at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrvbv/12/)

> It is a feature of HTML that all white space is treated identically. Any sequence of white-space characters is treated as a single space.

(Quote via: http://www.maproom.co.uk/invis1.htm)

To prevent the gap from appearing while maintaining the indentation, you can use either of the following tricks:

1. Moving the `>` of the `label` tag to the next line. Although this is [valid HTML](http://imageshack.us/a/img40/3931/valithtml.png), this may be confusing and not what you want.
2. Commenting out the whitespace between the tags (by placing it between `<!--` and `-->`).

   *Both of these options are wasting bandwidth.*
3. Putting the whitespace between tags for your server-side programming language, for example `<?php /*whitespace*/ ?>`. This may cause a low increase in server load.

All of these options are confusing and probably not what you want, so I'd recommend simply leaving out the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

No

Try to remove

```
padding-right: 7px;
```

in the CSS

This doea the trick

```
.FormStyle label {
 display: inline-block; 
 width: 130px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #666;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```